# What is the largest radius that the circular track can have such that the car remains in contact with the track?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, energy-conservation, potential-energy

> A car is travelling at $u$ as it enters a vertical loop of radius $r$.
>
> What is the largest value of $r$ that the track can have such that the car goes up and around the track whilst remaining in contact with the track?

My initial approach and the one that other people seem to agree on is: $$\frac{1}{2}mu^2=mgh=mg(2r)=2mgr$$

$$r=\frac{u^2}{4g}$$

But that means that the car comes to a stop at the highest point and should not continue such that it will come down the opposite side of the loop. Shouldn't the car require some velocity at the peak of the loop to remain in contact?

I approached this from another direction.

Take $\theta$ as the angle above horizontal from the centre of the loop.

The height $h$ will then be: $$h=r+r\sin\theta = r(1+\sin\theta)$$

The velocity $v$ at any time will be: $$\frac{1}{2}mu^2=\frac{1}{2}mv^2+mgh$$

$$v^2=u^2-2gh=u^2-2gr(1+\sin\theta)$$

The outward force will be: $$F=F_c-F_g \sin\theta$$ $$=\frac{mv^2}{r}-mg\sin\theta$$ $$=\frac{mu^2}{r}-2mg(1+\sin\theta)-mg\sin\theta$$

At the peak $\sin\theta=1$ and the outward force must not be less than zero so for the largest $r$: $$\frac{mu^2}{r}-5mg=0$$ $$r=\frac{u^2}{5g}$$

This means that at the peak the car much still have a velocity of: $$v_{peak}=\frac{u}{\sqrt{5}}$$

Have I gone wrong somewhere in my logic?

Which is the correct answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first method is incorrect;  it equates the potential energy at the top of the loop with the kinetic energy as the car enters the loop.

It thus assumes zero kinetic energy (and thus zero velocity) at the top of the loop.  The car will have fallen away from the track well before this  point.

The second method is correct, but perhaps needlessly complicated: Introducing a trig ratio of an angle, carrying it along for a while, and the setting the angle equal to $90^0$ seems like unnecessary work.  Simply look at the top of a successful loop, and set the available vertical force of gravity to the required centripetal force to find $v_{peak}$.

BTW, some sets of HotWheels came with a entry ramp and circular loop.  You could use the launch height to adjust the entry velocity.  Google "HotWheels centripetal force" for videos and experiments...